# Java validation from list

Tags: java, playframework

If I have a class and I want to check if the input to a property in that class is in a list, how would I do this?

Example

```
public class Length  {

    public static final List<String> ALLOWABLE_UNITS = 
        Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("inches", "feet", "meters", "millimeters"));

    public BigDecimal lengthValue;

    @SomeMatchingAnnotation(ALLOWABLE_UNITS)
    public String lengthUnit;
}
```

Is there an annotation to do that?  Would I have to create my own?

Comment: `ALLOWABLE_UNITS.contains(lengthUnit)`

Answer (score 1):

In the setter for your field you could do the validation like this:

```
public void setLengthUnit(String lengthUnit) {
  if (!ALLOWABLE_UNITS.contains(lengthUnit) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length unit not recognized.");
  }
  this.lengthUnit = lengthUnit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the play framework.  It creates the getters and setters for you.  You can define them yourself but I was hoping not to do that and use an existing annotation.  I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSR-303 to validate your beans then you can look for some custom validations, write yourself one, or just use `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`:

```
@Pattern(message="your message here" , regexp="^(meter|inch|cm)$")
public String lengthUnit;
```

**update**

If you want to pass dynamically built array of correct values then you should rather use custom validation. If you use `Hibernate Validator` as JSR-303 provider then you can alternatively use the `@ScriptAssert` annotation which allows you to define constraints using JSR-223 compatible scripting engine:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.possibleValues.indexOf(_this.lengthUnit) > -1")
```

Please note that I did not run above example, but it should work as expected.

Alternatively you can add constraint in on-the-fly mode (still assuming that you use Hibernate Validation).

```
ConstraintMapping customMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
customMapping.type(Length.class).property("lengthUnit", FIELD).constraint(new PatternDef().regexp("^(mm|cm|inch)$"));

HibernateValidatorConfiguration cfg = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
cfg.addMapping(customMapping);

ValidatorFactory vf = cfg.buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = vf.getValidator()
```

Comment: Thanks.  But there is not a built in way for me to pass the array to that annotation, correct?  I'm going to have to create my own validation annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html) is a good choice.  If you elect to use it, place the `hibernate-validator` JAR on your classpath.  I'm using the most recent version for this example, 5.1.1.Final.

There's a lot of code that has to be shown for it to work, but it's really three parts:

- An annotation on the field to specify that this is the element that needs to be validated,
- The standard implementation of the annotation itself, and
- The implementation of the `ConstraintValidator` for that annotation and object type.

First, the bean:

```
public class Length {

    @ValidUnit // this is the annotation we will use to validate.
    private String inputUnit;

    public String getInputUnit() {
        return inputUnit;
    }

    public void setInputUnit(final String inputUnit) {
        this.inputUnit = inputUnit;
    }
}
```

The field is a `String`; we'll need to remember that for later.

Next, the annotation.  Hibernate mandates that a `message()`, `groups()`, and a `payload()` be present.  Only the message is required by JSR-303, I believe.  So, we'll keep the implementation vanilla and only implement the few things we believe we need.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidUnitValidator.class)
public @interface ValidUnit {

    String message() default "Not a supported unit.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

The `@Constraint` annotation above this class tells Hibernate which class to use for the validation of the type.  So, let's implement that.

The declaration for anything that implements `ConstraintValidator` is an annotation and a type `T`.  We're trying to validate `String`, so we put that in place of `T` in our implementation.

```
public class ValidUnitValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUnit, String> {

    private final Set<String> validUnits = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("inches", "feet", "meters", "millimeters"));

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ValidUnit validUnit) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return validUnits.contains(value);
    }
}
```

Ultimately, it's a bit ceremonial compared to the more straightforward approach of validating in-line.  However, this gives you a neater separation of concerns; should you want to change what is a valid unit (you may want to add light-years next), you only need to modify and test one class.